# Adding the YouTube iframe to a Cordova app on iOS

Tags: iframe, cordova, youtube

I'm using Cordova 3.0 and am trying to embed a YouTube video inside an article of my news app. The YouTube code looks like this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In its current form the code does nothing except leave a large wide white square in the DOM. When I inject the letters `http:` so that it looks like this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

then the app automatically quits and goes to the browser. How can I just make the iframe behave as it should, as a little window. I have followed [the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661881/how-to-embed-youtube-video-in-phonegap-ios-app) mentioned in this question and have tried fiddling with the `<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />` line in the config.xml file.

Comment: What version of Android are you using?  This might help:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091273/youtube-iframe-in-jquery-mobile-phonegap-build

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for 
[Force HTML5 youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video)

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM?html5=1"></iframe>
```

OR may be

[Show Youtube video source into HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag)

Step 1: add &html5=True to your favorite youtube url

Step 2: Find  tag in source

Step 3: Add controls="controls" to video tag:

```
<video controls="controls" 
       class="video-stream" 
       x-webkit-airplay="allow" 
       data-youtube-id="N9oxmRT2YWw" 
       src="http://v20.lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Coc%3AU0hPRVRMVV9FSkNOOV9MRllD&amp;itag=43&amp;ipbits=0&amp;signature=D2BCBE2F115E68C5FF97673F1D797F3C3E3BFB99.59252109C7D2B995A8D51A461FF9A6264879948E&amp;sver=3&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;expire=1300417200&amp;key=yt1&amp;ip=0.0.0.0&amp;id=37da319914f6616c"></video>
```

More SF posts:
[YouTube video in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520113/youtube-video-in-html5)
[Force HTML5 youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video)